# Twisted compilation failed in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, crossbar

> I am trying to install Crossbar in my ubuntu 14.04. 
>  I installed the
>   dependencies as per the  instruction [here](http://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Linux/). 
>  When I am trying to
>   install cross the twisted installation fails.   
> I am having python
>   2.7.6. I installed all the python-devl packages and all are up to date.  I am getting the below error when I execute "pip install
>   crossbar".

```
copying twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport/winsock_pointers.c -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/twisted/internet/iocpreactor/iocpsupport
copying twisted/python/sendmsg.c -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/twisted/python
copying twisted/test/raiser.c -> build/lib.linux-i686-2.7/twisted/test
running build_ext
cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -I/usr/lib/pypy/include -c conftest.c -o conftest.o
building 'twisted.runner.portmap' extension
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/twisted
creating build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/twisted/runner
cc -O2 -fPIC -Wimplicit -I/usr/lib/pypy/include -c twisted/runner/portmap.c -o build/temp.linux-i686-2.7/twisted/runner/portmap.o
twisted/runner/portmap.c:10:20: fatal error: Python.h: No such file or directory
include <Python.h>
compilation terminated.error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: what is the location of "Python.h"?

Comment: /usr/include/python2.7/Python.h

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have the dev files installed from pypy? I don't use Ubuntu, but I believe the package is called pypy-dev. I contains a proper Python.h.

The one you mention belongs to the main Python installation. `/usr/include/python2.7/Python.h`

Comment: Great ..It worked ..Can i use the standard python itself for the further Crossbar development ...

Comment: I don't see why not. I understand that Pypy is the exception, not Python. But, admittedly, I've never used Crossbar. From their page it seems clear that they actually mean 'normal' Python though.

Comment: FWIW, Crossbar.io runs fine on PyPy. The recipe under http://crossbar.io/docs/Installation-on-Linux/ does mention steps to get started on PyPy.